# Up one level in JAR resource

Tags: java, jar, path, classpath

I have the following package hierarchy:

```
base--images--img.png
    |
    --code--Foo.java
    |
    --Base.java
```

That is, I have a package `base` which has 2 subpackages, `base.images` and `base.code` with respective files in each. `Base.java` just calls a method in `Foo`.

All of this gets bundled into `base.jar` when I build.

The problem: How can `Foo.java` load `img.png` no matter where the jar is located or run from?

Some things I've tried:

```
new File("../images/img.png")
Foo.class.getResource("../images/img.png")
```

Neither of these work because the `"../images/img.png"` is appended to the path the JAR is run from, not the path of the class.

---

MWE:

In Foo.java:

```
package base.code;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = Foo.class.getResource("/graphs/1.png");

        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Image not found!");
        }
    }

}
```

In Base.java:

```
package base;

public class Base {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        Foo.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are on the class path, never use a File. They might be stored in the jar (zip format).

The solution is simply to use an absolute path. That is more clear than a class package's relative path.

```
Foo.class.getResource("/base/images/img.png")
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that starting with / was an absolute path from the JAR.